# Is it possible to call upon a value specified in a program when using a function, without writing it in the function itself?

Tags: c, scope

I'm new to C programing and starting to learn, and I'm wondering whether it is possible to use some sort of integer across a number of functions, such that by changing it in one place, it will automatically be changed in all of the functions?

For example, let's say I have a function like:

```
int add_const(int number){
    int total;
    total = number - CONST;
    return total;
} //where CONST would be a value written somewhere else

int sub_const(int number){
    int total;
    total = number - CONST; //again, CONST is a value written somewhere else
    return total;
}
```

I would like for `CONST` to be a value a user can change, for example by using the `scanf` command, and for it to be in one place. Is something like that possible?

I tried using `#define`, but i don't think you can change it later, and also when i use a bunch of values like that it quickly becomes overwhelming

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It seems like a global variable would work. Have you considered or tried that?

Comment: Aren't you just talking about a _global_ variable? (e.g.) `int myglobal; int abc(int x) { return x + myglobal; } int def(int x) { return x * myglobal; }` If you change the value in `myglobal`, it is instantly reflected in all functions.

Comment: Oh, a global variable. Thank you very much! Again, I'm just learning and honestly didn't know i could do that.

Comment: Also, avoid global variables whenever possible.  They make your code hard to reason about and test.

Comment: he keyword ```static``` on a variable inside a function, extends the lifetime of a that variable to the lifetime of the program itself. As such you can define ```static int CONST``` inside the first function it is used and that's it.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh That doesn't provide a way to change it elsewhere in the program.

Answer (score 1):

A [file scoped](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope) variable (a *"global"*) can be used to achieve this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int shared = 42;

int add_shared(int number)
{
    return number + shared;
}

int sub_shared(int number)
{
    return number - shared;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Before: %d %d\n", add_shared(10), sub_shared(99));
    shared = 51;
    printf("After: %d %d\n", add_shared(10), sub_shared(99));
}
```

```
Before: 52 57
After: 61 48
```

<sup>*(Aside: The example uses slightly different identifiers. Uppercase identifiers are usually used for actual constants or macros. The lowercase `const` would conflict with the [keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/const).)*</sup>

Sometimes file scoped variables are useful, but more often than not they create code fragmentation and functions that are too tightly bound. Both of these can cause code to be hard to reason about and debug. The usual advice (especially for beginners) is to avoid global variables whenever possible.

Consider the following program that produces much the same output using block scoped variables, with the benefit that `add` and `sub` are now [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) that can be reused in other contexts.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int sub(int a, int b)
{
    return a - b;
}

int main(void)
{
    int shared = 42;
    printf("Before: %d %d\n", add(10, shared), sub(99, shared));
    shared = 51;
    printf("After: %d %d\n", add(10, shared), sub(99, shared));

    printf("Other: %d\n", add(101, 101));
}
```

It is a rather trivial example, but as a program grows controlling scope becomes more and more important.

---

A notable use of global variables in the standard library is [`errno`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error)<sup>1</sup>.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    errno = ERANGE;
    perror("Whoops");
}
```

```
Whoops: Numerical result out of range
```

<sup>1. Technically, `errno` is a macro that expands to a thread local modifiable `int`.</sup>